# asyncio wait - process results as they come

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

This script should take a list of initial tasks (URLs) and asynchronously make requests with `aiohttp`. And this part is done correctly. The problem is, since `asyncio wait` doesn't return actual results but only `done/pending task set`, I cant figure out where and how to process the results as they come, to make more requests and write data to DB. In this variant I placed the creation for a new `task` (make more requests...) inside the first one, which doesn't work.
PS. I am using `wait` because a book I am reading suggests using `wait` for more control over done and pending tasks and exceptions. Appreciate any help:)

```
async def fetch_content_2(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as result:
        res = await result.text()
        try:
            new_link = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml').select_one('element on website 2')['href'])
            # ***PROCESS AND WRITE SOME DATA TO DB***
        except:
            pass

async def fetch_content_1(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as result:
        res = await result.text()
        try:
            link = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml').select_one('element on website 1')['href'])
            # ***MAKE ANOTHER ASYNC REQUEST WITH NEW LINK***
            asyncio.create_task(fetch_content_1(session,link))
        except:
            pass

async def main(tasks):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        pending = [asyncio.create_task(fetch_content_1(session, url)) for url in tasks]
        while pending:
            done, pending = await asyncio.wait(pending, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

            # print(f'Done count: {len(done)}')
            # print(f'Pending count: {len(pending)}')

asyncio.run(main([url1, url2, ...]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`done` and `pending` are `set`s of `asyncio.Task` objects. If you want to get the result of the task or its state you must get the values of the sets and call the method you need, check the ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-object)). Specifically you can get the result invoking the `result` method.

```py
async def main(tasks):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        pending = [asyncio.create_task(fetch_content_1(session, url)) for url in tasks]
        while pending:
            done, pending = await asyncio.wait(pending, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
            res = done.pop().result()
            # do some stuff with the result
```

Check the documentation to see the possible exceptions of call the `result` method and related methods. A exception may occur if the task had an internal error or the result is not ready (in this case shouldn't happen).

Comment: It worked. Probably had a bug earlier when I tried using `result`. And I tried so many times. Thank you very much!